# wso2 slow when converting xml to json

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log>
        <property name="Request received to" value="Test2"/>
    </log>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var start = new Date().getTime();var payload = mc.getPayloadXML();var requestId = payload..*::requestId.toString();var timeStamp = payload..*::timeStamp.toString();var msisdn = payload..*::msisdn.toString();var keyWord = payload..*::keyWord.toString();for(var i=0;i<payload..*::dataSet.param.length();i++)     {         if(payload..*::dataSet.param[i].id.toString()=="order_id"){         var orderId =payload..*::dataSet.param[i].value.toString();      }         if(payload..*::dataSet.param[i].id.toString()=="entity_id")          {              var entity_id =payload..*::dataSet.param[i].value.toString();          }      }var end = new Date().getTime();var timeTaken = end - start; print("Time Duration :  " + timeTaken + " ms "); var start2 = new Date().getTime();mc.setPayloadJSON(  {     "Request":{        "request_id":requestId,      "action":"CancelOrder",      "request_timestamp":"208042019210259",      "source_node":"CRM",      "userid":"1",      "username":"SuperAdmin",      "dataset":{           "param":[              {                 "id":"order_id",                  "value":"11265878971023"            },   {                 "id":"sub_order_id",                    "value":"11265878766755"            },            {                 "id":"entity_id",               "value":"003"            }         ]      }   }});var end2 = new Date().getTime();var timeTaken2 = end2 - start2;print("Time taken for set to payload  :  " + timeTaken2 + " ms ");]]></script>
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <failover>
                <endpoint name="FirstUrl">
                    <http method="POST" uri-template="http://10.0.0.75:8080/Sampleproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/XMLtoJSON">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>5000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <errorCodes>101503,101504,101505,101507</errorCodes>
                            <initialDuration>100</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>3000</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint name="SecoundUrl">
                    <http method="POST" uri-template="http://10.0.0.75:8080/Sampleproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/XMLtoJSON">
                        <timeout>
                            <duration>5000</duration>
                            <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                        </timeout>
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <errorCodes>101503,101504,101505,101507</errorCodes>
                            <initialDuration>100</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>3000</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                    </http>
                </endpoint>
            </failover>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[var statusCode , statusDescription;var resultCode= mc.getPayloadJSON().Response.result_code.toString();if(resultCode == "SC000"){statusCode = "SC0000";statusDescription = "SUCCESS";}else{statusCode = "SC0001";statusDescription = "FAILURE";}mc.setPayloadXML(<Response><statusCode>{statusCode}</statusCode><statusDescription>{statusDescription }</statusDescription></Response>        );]]></script>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
    <respond/>
</inSequence>
```

above is my flow   am trying to convert below xml

```
<Request>
    <requestId><![CDATA[12310209842389]]></requestId>
    <timeStamp><![CDATA[2019/12/25 12:12:12]]> </timeStamp>
    <msisdn> <![CDATA[865545]]></msisdn>
    <keyWord><![CDATA[CANCEL_ORDER_API]]></keyWord>
    <dataSet>
        <param>
            <id><![CDATA[order_id]]></id>
            <value><![CDATA[12310209842396]]></value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <id><![CDATA[entity_id]]></id>
            <value><![CDATA[1]]></value>
        </param>
    </dataSet>
</Request>
```

to json and then call url and responce in json to xml

i can only fire upto 70 tps it will reach max of 120 tps and decreases to 40 and  again increases to 120

in script mediator **sc.setPayloadJSON();** takes around 50 to 200 ms in each request

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The script mediator is not recommended in situations where you are having high TPS or large payloads. This will result in a significant performance impact on mediation.

If you need to improve the performance you can either use a class mediator [1] or use the existing mediators to implement the solution. In your case, it seems like a simple data mapping is required. Therefore you can try to replace the existing script mediator with a payload factory mediator. You can refer to the sample in [2] to build your payload factory mediator.

The necessary values for the JSON payload can be obtained with XPATHs [3]

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Class+Mediator
[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/PayloadFactory+Mediator#PayloadFactoryMediator-Example2:JSON
[3]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Accessing+Properties+with+XPath